# Xcode How to stop Video embed youtube

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uicollectionview

I have Question about `UIWebview`

I need to stop youtube video when I go to another page

this is my code :

```
 if (currentPage > 0 && currentPage < [book count]-1) {
     [[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:currentPage-1]reload];
     [[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:currentPage+1]reload];
}
```

It's very nice when I use with `pageControl` but is not good for `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`

I try to go like this

```
if (currentPage > 0 && currentPage < [book count]-indexPath.item) {
    [[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:currentPage-indexPath.item]reload];
    [[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:currentPage+indexPath.item]reload];
}
```

Sometime is work but sometime is not. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to create `for` for loop book page like this

```
        for(int i = 0; i < _pageAmount ; i++)
        {
        if (currentPage > 0 && currentPage < [book count]-1) {
            [[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i]reload];
            }
        }
```

It's works fine,Thank you for Any Idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use youtube iframe api for embedding video like in this [guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) Then you can call

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"player.pauseVideo()"];
```

when you go to another page.

Comment: Thank you very much @AHTOH I'm use youtube embed but I don't need to change code in HTML page.